# Passing a Class Alias to usort

Tags: php, alias, autoload, usort

I have a comparison function in a service class in namespace:

`Company\Product\Services\Specific`

which I import in to my Controller like:

`use Company\Product\Service\Specific as SpecificService;`

I have an array that I wish to sort in this Controller class:

`usort ($array, 'SpecificService::sortFunction()');`

However, this trips up my autoloader, which searches for a class literal `SpecificService`, which does not exist.  I can, however, get around this:

`usort ($array, 'Company\Product\Services\Specific::sortFunction()');`

I'm picky and want to use my alias.  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
use SomeNamespace\String\Tools as StringTools;
```

and then, inside your method:

```
$arr  = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'b'];
$func = function ($a, $b) {
    return StringTools::cmp($a, $b);
    // or
    // $st = new StringTools();
    // return $st->cmp($a, $b);
    // if cmp isn't static
};
usort($arr, $func);
```

Assuming that:

```
public static function cmp($a, $b)
{
    // do comparison here
    return strcmp($a, $b);
}
```

and it's in a `SomeNamespace\String\Tools as StringTools;` namespace.

This way, your autoloader should work properly

If the method isn't static, you're gonna have to instantiate the classs in the anonymus function

Comment: Seems so obvious now.  Thank you for your response.